# Print Rails version in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm wondering how to display the current Rails version in a view. I already know that this will print the current Ruby version:

```
<%= RUBY_VERSION %>
```

But I'm not sure how to do this for Rails.

Edit: I tried to use `<%= debug(request.env) %>` to list all environment variables; unfortunately the Rails version isn't one of them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just do :

```
<%= Rails.version %>
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy! I should have figured that out.